# Можно ли подгружать рекламу Google спустя время?

Tags: javascript

Как мера обхода Adblock подумал, а можно ли как-то попробовать подгружать рекламу гугла, спустя пару секунд, например?

Comment: можно блоки с рекламой добавлять через таймер  динамически из js, хотя думаю такие способы обхода уже отловили.